# Multiple clicks at the same time using UiAutomator

Tags: android-uiautomator

I want to test an undesired user action using UiAutomator. The user may click on two buttons on the screen at the same time. Is is possible to simulate two or more simultaneous clicks using UiAutomator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: exactly at same time? No. But you can make uiObjects ready and do several `uiObject.click()` without any delay between them.The delay between execution of clicks would be very minimal and may not able to detect.  Alternatively `click()` on different threads. I haven't tried though.

Comment: If you can do it yourself manually and you just need an automated way to do this- you can try https://github.com/rils/ARP/wiki